# How can I timeout my hotspot?

Tags: wi-fi, wifi-hotspot, 3g, wifi-tethering

I use my hotspot on the go, then forget to switch to Wifi when I reach my home or office. Is there an app that times-out the hotspot -- and cellular data in general -- and switches to Wifi? It coudl do this after a certain amount of time or when it detects one of a known list of Wifi SSIDs.

Nexus 4
Android 5.0.1

Comment: Device, Android info?. In my devices, both Stock and CM ROMs, my hotspot automatically gets switch-off after some minutes. In older 4.x versions of Android, there was a time-out option. Kitkat and subsequent versions don't have options to tweak and use some default time-out.

Comment: You can also achieve your task using [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). Though I'm not sure whether this can work out without root. There are some apps available on Play Store and someone actually answered it on AE, I just can't find that answer. I'll ping here if I get to know that answer again.

Comment: Nexus 4, Android 5.0.1

Answer (score 1):

Apps are incapable of switching moblie networks on/off as this uses up minutes. To bypass this you require a root. However I believe apps can detect if wifi is in range. So when you get near wifi you can have an app notify you. Although I don't think there is a specific app that will check if wifi is in range. I recommended requesting an app like this somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like an opportunity for someone. 

It would have to detect specific Wifi SSIDs, since there are too many Wifi spots, including unsecured ones, that are low-quality or require login.